# Is it possible to capture values from a repeating regex group in xsl:analyze-string?

Tags: regex, xslt

I want to do something like this:

```
<xsl:analyze-string select="'ABCD'" regex="(A|B|C|D)+">
  <xsl:matching-substring>
     <xsl:for-each select="regex-group(1)">
         <letter><xsl:value-of select="." /></letter>
     </xsl:for-each>                    
  </xsl:matching-substring>
</xsl:analyze-string>
```

=>

```
<letter>A</letter>
<letter>B</letter>
<letter>C</letter>
<letter>D</letter>
```

But it doesn't appear to be possible because `xsl:analyze-string` only keeps the last value captured in a group, so the actual output is just:

```
<letter>D</letter>
```

The general problem is dealing with known values that may appear in unknown orders.

Comment: It would be nice to have a better description of the problem; your example is so trivial that it's hard to extrapolate from it to see what the real requirement is.

Comment: @MichaelKay A less trivial example might be parsing a URL into its component parts: `(https?://mydomain.com)(/search|/browse)?([\?&amp;](q=.*|a=.*|b=.*)){1,3}`

Comment: The answer is to break the problem into parts. More specifically, break the URI into parts, and then examine them individually. Don't rely on a single monster regular expression to do the whole job.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`xsl:analyze-string` will automatically repeat and match multiple times within a string. If you rewrite the expression to match substrings - instead of using anchors and/or explicitly repeating groups to match the whole string at once - you can get the correct output:

```
<xsl:analyze-string select="'ABCD'" regex="(A|B|C|D)">
  <xsl:matching-substring>
   <letter><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)" /></letter>
  </xsl:matching-substring>
</xsl:analyze-string>
```

=>

```
<letter>A</letter>
<letter>B</letter>
<letter>C</letter>
<letter>D</letter>
```

However, this becomes more complicated if some parts of the expression are strictly ordered and some are not. For example, say there are two unordered groups that themselves are ordered:

```
(1|2|3|4)+(A|B|C|D)+
```

Rewriting this regex as `(1|2|3|4)|(A|B|C|D)` would still make it possible to get a result of (using as input `21CB`):

```
<number>2</number>
<number>1</number>
<letter>C</letter>
<letter>B</letter>
```

But the rewritten regex would also match `AB12`, `1A3C`, etc., none of which match the original expression. I would be very interested if someone has a better solution to this. The ideal solution would be to retain previous captures of repeated groups, like in .NET.

Comment: Unfortunately xsl:analyze-string will only capture the last match. This is because it's designed to be implementable using widely available regex engines, and many regex engines have this limitation.